# Can you point me to an example of using cucumber.js with frisby.js?

Tags: cucumberjs, frisby.js

We would like to use frisby.js withing cucumber steps. 
Can anyone point me to an example which does the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible since frisbyjs needs jasmine-node (a BDD library) to run.

One alternative could be using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) instead frisbyjs. It could be easily integrated with Cucumber, jasmine-node or other BDD js library.